# How to create a sidebar for chromeextension using angular without iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension using Angular and my extension is similar like MaxAI chrome extension when the user clicks on the widget it opens the sidebar.

I have tried few tutorials to create a sidebar but the sidebar contains iframe. Without using iframe is it possible to create a sidebar similar like this

[image]

I have inspected the MaxAI sidebar where i could see that they haven't used iframe rather i could see some special tags added in the DOM like below

```
use-chat-gpt-ai
```

[image]

Here is my implementation using iframe

```
function injectAngularApplication() {
  var angularApplicationIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  angularApplicationIframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html');
  angularApplicationIframe.id = 'angularApplication';
  angularApplicationIframe.allow = 'clipboard-read; clipboard-write';
  angularApplicationIframe.className = 'angular_application_iframe';

  document.body.appendChild(angularApplicationIframe);
}
```

Which injects my Angular application into the iframe. The reason why i don't want to use the iframe is when we reload the frame it show empty even though i have added hashrouting.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "angularchrome",
  "description": "AngularChrome Extension.",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "/assets/icons/Icon.png",
    "default_title": "Click me!"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/assets/icons/Icon.png",
    "32": "/assets/icons/Icon.png",
    "48": "/assets/icons/Icon.png",
    "128": "/assets/icons/Icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "css": ["content.css"]
    }
  ],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "index.html",
        "toolbar.html",
        "toolbar.scss",
        "toolbar.js",
        "/assets/icons/ICON.png",
        "main.ts"
      ],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note:I don't want to use the sidepanel provided by chrome.

Can anyone suggest me some better insights on how to create a chrome extension using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I made open-source project called [Rafflesia](https://github.com/fleker/rafflesia). In it, I use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/content-scripts) to generate DOM elements and insert them into the page context.

Here's a snippet from my [content-script.js](https://github.com/Fleker/rafflesia/blob/master/src/content-script.js):

```js
const scriptsToLoad = ['webpage-script.js'];
scriptsToLoad.forEach(script => {
  const s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL(script);
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
  s.onload = function () {
    s.remove();
  };
});

const toggler = document.createElement('button')
toggler.innerText = '▲'
toggler.style.position = 'fixed'
// ...
toggler.onclick = toggle
document.body.appendChild(toggler)

const heightAdjuster = document.createElement('div')
heightAdjuster.innerText = '⋯'
heightAdjuster.style.position = 'fixed'
// ...
heightAdjuster.onmousedown = adjustEnter
// ...
document.body.appendChild(heightAdjuster)
```

This part is all vanilla JS because it's quite hard to create the build environment using Angular and inserted into the page. You'd have to (1) manually build the Angular project (2) move it into the extension directory (3) repackage the extension (4) reload the extension in your browser (5) reload the page you want. As such, part of my DOM insertion does include an iframe for the bulk of the content so I can change it more easily.

But to get around your issue, I do insert a [`webpage-script.js`](https://github.com/Fleker/rafflesia/blob/master/src/webpage-script.js) into the page so that I can use [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) between my iframe and the webpage so that I can pass data and keep things synchronized.

```
// Add event listeners into the Overleaf page that can respond to events from
// our external site.
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  const {data} = e
  const parsedEvent = data
  const parsedData = parsedEvent.data
  switch (parsedEvent.type) {
    case 'rafflesia_copy':
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(parsedData)
      break;
    // ...
  }
})
```

My Angular service can then create typed `Event` objects and [communicate with the webpage](https://github.com/Fleker/rafflesia/blob/master/src/app/tools/citations/citations.component.ts):

```js
  copy() {
    if (!this.bibtex) return // Nothing
    const msg: Event = {
      type: 'rafflesia_copy',
      data: this.bibtex
    }
    window.parent.postMessage(msg, '*')
  }
```

and this can occur in reverse:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('message', e => {
      const parsedEvent = e.data
      if (parsedEvent?.type === 'rafflesia_getProjectFiles') {
        const files = parsedEvent.data.map((x: any) => x.name)
          .filter((x: string) => x.endsWith('.bib'))
        this.mainbib = files
      }

      if (parsedEvent?.type === 'rafflesia_read') {
        this.draft = parsedEvent.data
        this.parse()
      }
    })

    this.refreshProjectFiles()
  }
```

It does result in a few more files to build out, and a bit more to track, but it improves the build and iterative process.